# Why no article for 'tomorrow' but there is for 'morrow'?

Tags: word-usage, articles, definite-article

I searched for the word 'morrow' and found out that it takes the definite article 'the'. It's an old word but still in use as I refer COCA. One of the example is:

> the postbox by the door where it would not be noticed until **the morrow**

My question is,

'morrow' is a noun and so is 'tomorrow'. Both mean **the same,** but then why the word 'morrow' takes the definite article and 'tomorrow' does not! Say--

> It is reserved till the morrow **BUT** 
>  It is reserved till <del>the</del> tomorrow.

If both mean **the next day**, and there should be **only** one day, 'the' seems okay with 'morrow' but not with 'tomorrow'.

Comment: a pure guess, but tomorrow might actually be a contraction of the morrow, so 'the' is already included. (edit) a bit of googling tells me I was half right - http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=tomorrow

Comment: Note that "morrow" is an obsolete word. Unless you're quoting Shakespeare, say "tomorrow", not "the morrow".

Comment: @Jay but then the coca shows that it has been in use even these years. I mentioned it

Comment: @MaulikV You'd have to look at a list of the actual usages. I strongly suspect that you would find that almost all are either quotes from older writing, poetry, or historical novels. No one says, "We guarantee delivery of your new cell phone on the morrow. Forsooth, my liege."

Comment: ... "And we pray it giveth thee good bounty in thy missives to yon fair damsel." Hey, I need to put messages like this on websites I build.

Comment: Maulik, if it is used at all today it would be in a limited regional context. In any dialect of American English it would be seen as an intentional archaism.

Comment: @Jay: Sorry, but you're wrong.  It may not be used by those with a limited vocabulary, or to an audience expected to include such individuals, but it's far from obsolete.

Comment: @jamesqf Well, I think I'm a reasonably intelligent and well-educated person -- went to college, have a professional job, and all that -- and I mostly hang around with intelligent and well-educated people. And I am hard-pressed to think of a case where anyone I know ever said "I will do this on the morrow", or where I have read such a phrase in print, other than quoting something written hundreds years ago or mimicking the language of that time. Of course I can't say how you and your friends talk among yourselves, but if you use "the morrow" in everyday conversation, I think you are very, ...

Comment: ... very rare among English-speaking people. If you can point to some modern books or webpages that say "the morrow", outside of the contexts I've mentioned, I'd be interested in seeing them.

Comment: Yes, *morrow* is archaic.  Sometimes people deliberately use archaisms for one reason or another, but that doesn't make it part of modern English.  As for *tomorrow*, that has no article incorporated—it's a temporal deictic pronoun, so like other pronouns, it doesn't take a determiner.

Comment: @Jay you are confusing an everyday word versus "not so common **but** used word" . I never said I've heard all speaking it everyday. And by the way why are we discussing more on archaic rather than the original question?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about etymology, which is suitable for [English.SE].

Answer (score 2):

Etymology created this quirk.

According to [Google's etymology](https://www.google.com/search?q=define%20tomorrow), "tomorrow" comes from middle english "to morrow" using the prepositional form of "to". The same is true of "today" and "tonight".

Just as you never say "night" or "day" without specifying which night/day (unless referring to the concept of night/day) you don't say "morrow" without specify *which* morrow. Adding the "to" fulfills that need by essentially saying "this" or "the immediately following". So the word "tomorrow" doesn't need that, because it's built in.

Note that *modern* english inherited the words "to", "morrow", and "tomorrow" from *middle* english - but not all of the specific details of those words that allows the combination to make sense. So we end up with confusing word combinations that don't quite have the same meaning as their parts.

Answer (score 1):

This might be an etymology matter, but if you check the definitions of [***morrow***](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/morrow)

> *noun
>   (archaic)*
>   1) morning
>   2) the next day
>   3) the time just after some particular event

it does not seem to be so specific as to meaning tomorrow specifically (def. 1 and 3). In those situations, an article would be appropriate:

> I will go home on **the morrow**.

meaning *morning*, similar to *I will go home in *the morning*.

Comment: This is correct. "Morrow" means "morning;" when it is used to mean "the following day" this is synechtoche.

Comment: This makes sense. +1